# Is there a way to secure access to android native libraries packaged within an apk or aar?

Tags: android, security, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have a native android library that I would like to secure such that only specific applications can load them. Is there a way to restrict loading to certain applications?

What is the general solution to establishing trust between lets say an Android application and a native library? How can a native library prevent unauthorized method calls?

Comment: There are no solutuons to this stronger than a "make it difficult to figure out how" as both halves of the program and the communication in between are subject to study.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks. Would you happen to have ideas on what some of those may be? Let's say I want to make it very difficult to figure out. What are some of the better ones?

Comment: Make it hard to understand what the calls and their arguments do; make it so that `replay attacks` don't work.  And keep in mind that you are always up against the alternative of someone re-implementing the functionality from scratch - you can only make figuring out how to use yours more expensive than that, beyond that it is out of your hands as they can just ignore your efforts and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Use some custom encryption and decryption in apk/aar native libs.The runtime decrypted native library and then can be System.load (from Java), or dlopened from any location on the filesystem, including the 'external/internal storage'. Even the file name may have no traces of lib or .so.